# Automatically detect right guard for logged in user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel **5.4** and added a new guard named `website` to my application and I did all things that are required for that.

But a problem that I have is that some views are shared between both **default** and `website` guard. for example when I want to show current logged in user I used this :

```
        <div class="pull-left info">
            @if(Auth::guard('website')->check())
                <p>{{Auth::guard('website')->user()->name}} Website</p>
            @elseif (Auth::check())
                <p>{{Auth::user()->name}}</p>
            `@endif
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
```

And this is just one place that I must to check which guard is logged in and it is Naturally difficult,time consuming and dirty way.

On the other hand some operations is same for both guards. for example there is a `bannerController` **store** method that can save some banner model for them like this (Of course this example is written just for `website` guard as you can see ):

```
public function store($website,StoreBannerAds $request)
{
    $allData = $request->all();
    $website = Auth::guard('website')->user();

    $ads = $website->banner_ads()->create($allData);

    $result = ['success' => true, 'generated_id' => $ads->banner_ads_id];
    return $result;

}
```

In this case if I want to store some banners for default user logged in User I should use an `if ()` or completely another **store** method:

```
public function store($website,StoreBannerAds $request)
    {
        $allData = $request->all();
        if (Auth::guard('website')->check()) {
            $model = Auth::guard('website')->user();
        } else if (Auth::check()){
            $model = Auth::user();
        }

        $ads = $model->banner_ads()->create($allData);

        $result = ['success' => true, 'generated_id' => $ads->banner_ads_id];
        return $result;

    }
```

I want know are there any clean and appropriate ways to do that Or I must to use this approach still؟

**Update:**

What I changed before in auth.php configuration file are these:

```
'defaults' => [
            'guard'     => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],

'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver'   => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
            'website' => [
                'driver'   => 'session',
                'provider' => 'websites',
            ],

            'api'     => [
                'driver'   => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],

'providers' => [
            'users'    => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model'  => App\User::class,
            ],
            'websites' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model'  => App\Website::class,
            ]
        ],

'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'table'    => 'password_resets',
                'expire'   => 60,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Something is logically wrong with this. If the user has been authenticated by a guard then you don't need to specify further along as it will be that guard for the whole code flow. If you want to switch logic/interface put a type flag on the user. Testing the guard type is pointless

Comment: @MikeMiller,means that if I use `Auth::guard('website')->validate()` to login a website user I just use `Auth::user()` for that ? But when use that it returns  `null` value but when used `Auth::guard('website')->user()` all things worked fine

Comment: Yes always just use `\Auth::user()`. You should apply your guard in the config or routes. Once the user is inside the controller they have already passed the guard. Use something on the user to decide what to do next

Comment: `You should apply your guard in the config or routes` how? can you guide me more?

Comment: You can help yourself by reading the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#protecting-routes and https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to hit the default guard to get the user. `Auth::user()` will use the current default guard.

If you always have any routes needing an authenticated user behind the default `auth` middleware, the default guard should be the correct guard for getting the user. If the route isn't behind the `auth` middleware and the user is a guest currently, it doesn't matter what guard `check` is called on.

The `Request` object will have access to the current user as well. Regardless of guard `$request->user()` should give you the current user.

Checking what guard is used could be done when calling `check` on a guard or asking the `AuthManager` for what the default guard is.

Some options:

```
@if (Auth::check())
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    @if (Auth::getDefaultDriver() == 'website')
        Website
    @endif
@endif
```

OR

```
@if (Auth::check())
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    @if (Auth::guard('webiste')->check())
        Website
    @endif
@endif
```

OR (if on 5.5)

```
@auth
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    @auth('website')
        Website
    @endauth
@endauth
```

Slims the lines down a little.

```
$model = $request->user();
// or
$model = Auth::user();
```

Comment: I tried your codes but when run `@if (Auth::check())` if a website guard user is logged in , it does no things and seem not equal to true.

Comment: are you using the `auth` middleware?

Comment: I used `auth:website` middleware for routes that were for website users and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it from your explanation. But, I do have a little solution from my understanding. For example using `helpers`.

```
if (! function_exists('auth_user')) {
    function auth_user($guard = 'website', $attr = null, $force = false)
    {
        $user = auth($guard)->check()
            ? auth($guard)->user()
            : $force && auth()->check()
                ? auth()->user()
                : null;

        return $user
            ? $attr
                ? $user->$attr
                : $user
            : null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// get name of the user
$name = auth_user('website', 'name');

// get the user
$user = auth_user()
```

***PS.*** What do you think if user is not authenticated? What is the value of the `$model`? Your example is very strange.

With this approach, at least you can simplify your code.

```
@if ($name = auth_user('website', 'name'))
    <p>{{ $name }} Website</p>
@elseif ($name = auth_user(null, 'name')) // or auth_user('website', 'name', true)
    <p>{{ $name }}</p>
@endif
```

and,

```
// force get user data although `website` guard fails
$model = auth_user('website', null, true);
```

Comment: $model only holds current logged-in user

Comment: Yeah I know, but you still using `else if (Auth::check())`..I mean you don't need it if controller only accessible by the logged user, use `else` instead.